# Call normal javascript function from another document in a react component function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to call a normal javascript function inside of a react component function.

The script tags are nested in the footer as following :

```
<script src="NORMAL JAVASCRIPT STUFF"></script> // function test(){};
<script src="REACT STUFF"></script>
```

So the javascript file with the function that I need is being read earlier.
So the function should be available in the whole document.

Now when I try to call the function within some react component function like that:

```
....,
someFunction: function(){
test();
},...
```

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`

Does anyone know how to access normal functions inside of react?

Comment: I tried what you have done, and call that test function in some components' `render`, it get called, can you post the code in that `NORMAL JAVASCRIPT STUFF`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help - I had to declare a window variable function to attach it to the window scope in order to use that in my react components

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That function would belong to the `window` object, so you would need to call `window.test();` instead.

See here:

https://jsfiddle.net/7dzdp9rw/

Comment: Your example works fine - I tried to replicate it but unfortunately I receive the error that window.test(); is not a function.

May it be because my funcion is 300lines long and includes 3 ajax calls and 1 react component ? ^^

Comment: A single function definitely should not contain 300 lines of code and multiple ajax requests, but that's an entirely different problem.  Typically, if your React component needs a helper function, you'd declare it in the component itself or use `require` to pull in a node module that can do it for you.  It usually isn't a very good idea to depend on a helper function otherwise.

Comment: fixed it - I had to declare it like that : window.test = function(){};

Comment: the helper function is required outside of the react component as well thats why it has to be declared outside :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've posted my guess is that you have `test` defined within a function.  If a variable or function is defined within another function, it is scoped to that function, and only available there.  It would not be globally available.  You would need to move the test definition to outside of any function within "NORMAL JAVASCRIPT STUFF".

e.g. if you have

```
function xyz {
    function test() {}
}()
```

you need to change to

```
function xyz() {}
function test() {}
```

OR

you can explicitly assign the function to the global scope

```
function xyz() {
    window.test = function() {}
}
```

As a general rule, you want to limit what you have in the global javascript "window" object so as to avoid conflicts.